# Super-luminal separation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, space-expansion

Suppose there are are 5 bodies separating in space (due to it's expansion), and let us consider that they can emit light.

1. 1st body moves in the -x direction, at the speed of light.
2. 2nd body    moves in the -x direction, at half the speed of light.
3. 3rd body stays    at rest at the origin, with respect to the other 4 bodies.
4. 4th body    moves in the +x direction, at half of the speed of
   light.
5. 5th body    moves in the +x direction, at the speed of light.

Will light from 1st and 2nd body reach the other 3 bodies? If not in any case, what will we see there (from where the light is not reaching to)? Will there be any change if the 1st and/or 5th body moves with a speed greater than that of the speed of light?

NOTE: Just to clear it up, they are not moving by themselves at all. The space they are in, is just expanding at a varying pace. I just did some research, and these are my views. It's well observed that the rate of expansion of space from any object increases as the distance increases. Maybe it's because of the long path to be covered by light to travel to us, and interaction of light due to interaction of light with rarer and denser medium of the universe, and maybe gravitational-lensing. The time is being synchronized, apparently making us believe that the objects are moving at a speed greater than the speed of light relative to us. Although in reality, it's just space-time interaction with the speed of energy and masses present. It's just relative, that's all.

Comment: Your question is buggy, according to spec relativity things can't move with speed of light. Thus, your (1) and (5) don't exist.

Comment: It's not about moving, it's about space expansion. Search for Hubble Sphere.

Comment: So it is your question much more interesting. I suggest to make more obvious they are not moving, but their distance changes due to the changing metric.

Comment: It's all relative after all.

Comment: To answer this question, it is not enough to know the velocities of the bodies at the time of the light emission, you would need to know the evolution of the scale factor $a(t)$.

Comment: Let's consider that the particles moving at the speed of light, lies on the surface of the ever expanding Hubble Sphere (having a radius equal to Hubble Length) formed with respect to the particle at rest (i.e 3rd particle). Also, the particles moving at half of the speed of light should lie at a specific radial distance within the Hubble Sphere, from the 3rd particle. So, is the scale factor still required?

Comment: I'm not sure about the answer, but see http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808 by Tamara Davis and Charles Lineweaver: _"We show that we can observe galaxies that have, and always have had, recession velocities greater than the speed of light._" It's a caterpillar on an elastic rope thing.